# Java script mini file breaking

Tags: javascript, server

I have a js file with some functionalities that works 100% on my local machine but once it has been deployed to the server, some functionality doesn't work. When I publish it creates es5 and es5.min extensions. When I trace why I cannot get the desired results I can see it is failing on es5.min which I don't know why it is like that. I have compared both files and their all look the same.

I am not too sure what those min files do and if needed or should be deleted as it is breaking while the original file is not breaking.

What might be the problem, is it a catch on

Uncaught TypeError: jqXHR.responseJSON is undefined
error https://serverurl/scripts/customer.es5.min.js?6.0:460

**Code : Line 460**

```
         build_chart_user_activity: function () {
            var self = reporting;

            //select all assigned
            self.form.assigned_users.find("option").prop("selected", true);

            var param = {
                start_date: self.form.start_date.val(),
                end_date: self.form.end_date.val(),
                usernames: self.form.assigned_users.val(),
                all_users: self.form.all_users_chk.prop("checked"),
                r: self.form.customer.val()
            };

            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                contentType: "application/json",
                url: "_content/customer.aspx/GetCustomer",
                data: JSON.stringify(param),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (result) {
                    var s = JSON.parse(result.d);
                    if (s.length > 0) {
                        self.charts.chart_data = s;
                        self.methods.build_data_table();
                        self.charts.chart_export_btn.prop("disabled", false);
                        self.charts.export_btn_toExcel.prop("disabled", false);
                    }
                    else {
                        self.methods.clear_data_table();
                    }
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    common.display_error(jqXHR.responseJSON.Message);  line 460: This is where it is failing.
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Looks like the JSON that is requested does not contain valid data?

Comment: Have you checked what response the server actually gave? Since this is in the error handler, maybe it wasn't actually JSON to begin with ...? (Think for example a classic 500 error, that is likely to result in an HTML response, rather than JSON.)

Comment: @NicoHaase I am trying to debug and one of the thing I did try to do is to duplicate the original script and name it xx.es5.min with no luck. I doubt if the data is invalid since I can get the expected result on my local machine. this is the param object results,

Data : {"start_date":"11/01/2021 12:00 AM","end_date":"01/18/2022 12:00 AM","usernames":null,"all_users":true,"r":"companyName"}

Comment: @CBroe how do i check that from the server?

Comment: Use your browser dev tools, network panel.

Comment: _"I doubt if the data is invalid since I can get the expected result on my local machine"_ - that's because your local machine responded the way you expected it to. But the other machine might not - due to different configuration, or other circumstances. DO NOT ever assume that because one system behaved one way, another system _must_ behave the same way. Always verify, instead of assuming.

Comment: I have checked the response and I am getting 504. the request is JSON

Comment: Yeah, then the API is broken. Code 504 means "Gateway timeout"